# JAVA, Should I use "import"?

Tags: java, import

### Code1

```
public class launcher{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"HelloWorld");
    }
}
```

### Code2

```
public class launcher{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("HelloWorld");
    }
}
```

### Code3

```
public class launcher{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int a = java.util.Random.nextInt(10);
    }
}
```

### Code4

```
import java.util.Random;
public class launcher{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Random rr = new Random();
        int num = rr.nextInt(10);
    }
}
```

Code1 and Code2 work well without "import java.swing.JOptionPane" or "import System.out.println"

But, Code3 doesn't work well.
Should I use like Code4?

Comment: `out` of `System` is not a class, but a `static` variable, so you can't "import" it, unless you use `import static`, but that might confuse a few people. As for `JOptionPane`, that comes down to how much you like typing.  The main reason for using the fully qualified name is when you have a naming conflict, like `java.utll.Date` and `java.sql.Date` and you want to use both in the same class

Comment: @guy The OP had a bunch of his question inside tag indicators (`<>`).  It should be more readable now.

Comment: I mean, Code1,2,4 does work well.

Comment: Thank you for editing, azurefrog :)

Comment: Thanks you. I understand now. :) @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem in "Code3" doesn't have anything to do with importing `Random` or using its fully qualified name.

Your problem is that `nextInt()` is not a static method.  "Code4" works because you create an instance of `Random` and run the `nextInt()` method on it, not because you've imported the class.

All that importing a class really does is save you from having to write out the package every time you want to use it.  It doesn't change the way you can invoke methods on that class.

"Code3" would work if you re-wrote it like this:

```
public class launcher{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        java.util.Random rr = new java.util.Random();
        int a = rr.nextInt(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you! I understand now :)